# Change a table cell data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am failing to figure how to change a particular cell data of a mysql database table.
For instance:

MyDB database has 3 tables
"Table1"
"Table2"
"Table3" etc.

Table 3 has 3 columns: ID | Title| Deadline
Each column has several rows (content created)

```
"Table3"
 ID | Title| Deadline
 1  | abc  | 30
 2  | def  | 45
 3  | ghi  | 30
```

etc.

So, let'say I want to change `30` with `60` from `Deadline` where `row ID is 3`, how do I do this?

When I type `UPDATE Table3 set deadline = '60' WHERE Deadline like 30;` 
it unfortunately also changes the  "30"  of the row where ID 1.

Many thanks for your clarification.

Roman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanna change the row ID with 3, then mention that in the where clause.

```
update table3 
set deadline=60 
where id=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE Table3
SET deadline=60
WHERE id=3;
```